# how do I read in tons of Json buckets using glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

really hope someone can help me with it..

I want to read in all json files in this path "s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/" how do i do it with glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options ?

if I do `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", format="json", connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/" ]})`, it won't work.

I had to list every single sub buckets ,I feel there should be a better way. For example: I had to do this `df0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", format="json", connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=12/" ,"s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=13/" ,"s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=14/" ,"s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=15/" ,"s3://.../year=2019/month=11/day=06/hour=20/minute=16/" ....]})`

I have thousands of sub buckets to list so I really appreciate any guidance on how I can make my life easier. thank you!!

Comment: Do you have a partitioned table created on this s3 path?

Comment: @bdcloud i think year, month, day, hour minutes are the partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution -> using "recurse" option when reading large group of files.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a Glue Crawler to create tables in the Glue Data Catalog. You can then use the tables via

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="mydb",
    table_name="mytable")
```

This AWS blog post explains how to deal with partitioned data in Glue https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to avoid crawler though